# Were There Programming Languages Before Compilers?

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system, history

Obviously there must have been a programming language to write a compiler for, but did people used to write in say COBOL (or whatever) and then hand compile it to assembly or was it all written in assembly until someone thought of a higher language? Thanks, ell.

Comment: This isn't entirely off-topic, but it might be a better fit on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question directly, programmers didn't use formal high-level languages and then convert to assembly by hand.  They used flow charts, which are a kind of graphical language, but then coded the assembly directly.  According to this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_chart#History) on flow charts, Von Neumann used them in 1947, right at the advent of electronic computing.

Before compilers most code was written in assembly language.  One could argue that an assembler was a primitive type of compiler, since it would convert *mnemonics* such as `mov reg1, [reg2]` into *op-codes*.

Before assemblers, op-codes were entered directly.  Since there was no read-only-memory, boot routines were entered by actually setting the bytes with switches on a [*front panel*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_panel).

The [*History of Compiler Construction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_compiler_construction) Wikipedia article might be helpful.

Comment: And the critical difference between an assembly language and a higher-level language (regardless of whether it's compiled or interpreted) is that an HLL program specifies *behavior*, whereas an assembly program specifies *machine code*.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Good point, although my comment was simply that strictly speaking, an assembler IS a compiler, albeit for a very LLL.

Comment: That depends on the meanings of the words "assembler" and "compiler".  The point could be (and has been!) argued at great length without illuminating anything other than what people mean by those two words.  (I personally think that the machine code vs. behavior distinction is most useful, but others of course will have different opinions.)

Answer (score 4):

The notion of *programming languages* and *compilers* evolved hand-in-hand. Grace Hopper is generally credited with having developed the first compiler:

> In 1952, Hopper completed her first compiler (for Sperry-Rand computer), known as the *A-0 System*. As she said later, she did this, because *she was lazy and hoped that the programmer may return to being a mathematician*.
>
> The A-0 System actually was a set of instructions that could translate symbolic mathematical code into machine language. In producing A-0, Hopper took all the subroutines she had been collecting over the years and put them on a tape. Each routine was given a call number, so that it the machine could find it on the tape. As described by Hopper—“All I had to do was to write down a set of call numbers, let the computer find them on the tape, bring them over and do the additions. This was the first compiler.”
>
> *Source: http://history-computer.com/ModernComputer/Software/FirstCompiler.html*

As stated on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-O), “The A-0 functioned more as a loader or linker than the modern notion of a compiler.” (It kind of literally *compiled* together subroutines, hence the name.) I don't have any more detailed references on hand at the moment, but you can imagine that the input that A-0 and similar programs could process evolved incrementally to be more complex—more like what is now called a “high-level programming language”—with compilers taking on more of their modern function as *translators* and not mere compilers of code (but the name stuck).

You can probably find more details in the transcript of the keynote address that Hopper gave at the first “History of Programming Languages” conference, as published in the [HOPL I conference proceedings](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=800025). If I remember well, she describes there how things evolved from A-0 to her later work that also inspired COBOL; but I didn't re-read the article yet myself.

It's interesting and amusing to note that Hopper says she encountered resistance to the idea of a program that wrote programs:

> “I had a running compiler, and nobody would touch it because, they carefully told me, computers could only do arithmetic; they could not do programs.”
>
> *Source: http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/5487/Grace%20Hopper%20completes%20the%20A-0%20Compiler*

Answer (score 3):

Sure.

[Plankalkül](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plankalk%C3%BCl) was proposed by Konrad Zuse back in 1943.   (Nobody wrote a compiler for it for 50 years, and the one that was written was done to simply to show it could be done).

Most other folks first invented various binary coding schemes followed by assemblers.

Fortran was probably the first "high level" language to see any wide spread usage.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers are usually bootstrapped. This means the compiler is written in a language for which a compiler exists already.

It is common that some compilers are written in the same language they compile: Mono Compiler is C#, Vala compiler is Vala.

In the case of Mono, it was compiled using Microsoft C# compiler until Mono was able to build itself. In the case of Vala, the compiler was (AFAIK) written in C until the point it could compile enough Vala to rewrite the compiler in Vala.

So you are right. Some compilers had to be written in assembly at some point, if no other compiler was available. Or at least a less capable version of the compiler writting in another language is included just to bootstrap the compiler.

Comment: I believe the OP wanted to know if programmers used formal languages to describe algorithms, but then convert to assembly language by hand.